# How to fetch cursor value with %ROWTYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql

i make a procedure as shown below i want to fetch cursor values and extract these values from other loop tell me best way here is my code

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST (P_EMP_ID     NUMBER,
                                                  TRIGER_BY    VARCHAR2)
AS
   CURSOR TO_HOD
   IS
      SELECT   EMP.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
               EMP.EMP_NAME,
               APR.LEFT_DT,
               APR.RESIGN_TYPE
        FROM   FSC_APPROVAL APR, CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V EMP
       WHERE       APR.HOD_APPR = 'Y'
               AND APR.ZONE_HD_APPR IS NULL
               AND EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = APR.EMP_ID;

   CURSOR TO_ZONE
   IS
      SELECT   EMP.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
               EMP.EMP_NAME,
               APR.LEFT_DT,
               APR.RESIGN_TYPE
        FROM   FSC_APPROVAL APR, CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V EMP
       WHERE       APR.HOD_APPR = 'Y'
               AND APR.ZONE_HD_APPR = 'Y'
               AND APR.TIM_OFC_APPR IS NULL
               AND EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = APR.EMP_ID;

   CUR_VAL            TO_HOD%ROWTYPE;
   CUR_VAL_FOR_LOOP   TO_HOD%ROWTYPE;
```

Here procedure begin

```
    BEGIN

       IF TRIGER_BY = 'HOD'
       THEN
          OPEN TO_HOD;

          LOOP
             FETCH TO_HOD INTO   CUR_VAL;

             EXIT WHEN TO_HOD%NOTFOUND;
          END LOOP;
       ELSIF TRIGER_BY = 'ZONE'
       THEN
          OPEN TO_ZONE;

          LOOP
             FETCH TO_ZONE INTO   CUR_VAL;

             EXIT WHEN TO_ZONE%NOTFOUND;
          END LOOP;

   END IF;
```

in above code just fetch my data and put in **cur_val** that was %rowtype
after that i fetch these values in new loop but its not make sense  and show error **PLS-00456: item 'CUR_VAL' is not a cursor**

```
LOOP
      ***FETCH CUR_VAL INTO   CUR_VAL_FOR_LOOP;***

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (CUR_VAL_FOR_LOOP.EMPLOYEE_CODE);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

i am face error on this line `FETCH CUR_VAL INTO   CUR_VAL_FOR_LOOP;`
please guide me how i make this procedure as i desire if you have better option then i warmly welcome if you have further query about my Question then i will here to describe you

Comment: i want to make only one variable, if i have only TO_HOD%TYPE it show it is for TO_HOD CURSOR and if i declare for TO_ZONE%TYPE it only for TO_ZONE CURSOR i want i have only one variable because only one cursor is run from these and that variable i pass in a loop

Comment: CUR_VAL is not a cursor, you can't fetch from it, it holds no definition to the query.

Comment: yes its not a cursor its %rowtype variable i am fetching cursor in variable

Comment: No, in your loop you're trying to fetch from a variable (CUR_VAL) into another (CUR_VAL_FOR_LOOP)...hence the CUR_VAL is not a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use two variables? You can do it shorter (not tested):

```
CURSOR TO_ALL(hd APR.ZONE_HD_APPR%TYPE) IS
  SELECT   EMP.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
           EMP.EMP_NAME,
           APR.LEFT_DT,
           APR.RESIGN_TYPE
    FROM   FSC_APPROVAL APR, 
              JOIN CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V EMP ON EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = APR.EMP_ID
   WHERE   APR.HOD_APPR = 'Y'
           AND NVL(APR.ZONE_HD_APPR, 'NULL') = NVL(hd, 'NULL')
           AND EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = APR.EMP_ID;

CUR_VAL TO_ALL%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

      OPEN TO_ALL(CASE TRIGER_BY WHEN 'HOD' THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'Y');
      LOOP
         FETCH TO_ALL INTO   CUR_VAL;
         ...
         EXIT WHEN TO_ALL%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;

END;
```