# How to stop repeating of row using %type and cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

i make a procedure as shown below i want to fetch cursor values and extract these values in a variables and extract these variable in a new loop but issue same row is repeated

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FSC.TEST (TRIGER_BY    VARCHAR2)
AS
   CURSOR TO_HOD
   IS
      SELECT   EMP.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
               EMP.EMP_NAME
               --APR.LEFT_DT,
              -- APR.RESIGN_TYPE
        FROM   FSC_APPROVAL APR, CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V EMP
       WHERE       APR.HOD_APPR = 'Y'
               AND APR.ZONE_HD_APPR IS NULL
               AND EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = APR.EMP_ID;

   CURSOR TO_ZONE
   IS
      SELECT   EMP.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
               EMP.EMP_NAME
             --  APR.LEFT_DT,
              -- APR.RESIGN_TYPE
        FROM   FSC_APPROVAL APR, CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V EMP
       WHERE       APR.HOD_APPR = 'Y'
               AND APR.ZONE_HD_APPR = 'Y'
               AND APR.TIM_OFC_APPR IS NULL

               AND EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = APR.EMP_ID;
   emp_code CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V.EMPLOYEE_CODE%type;
   emp_name CHR_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BI_V.EMP_NAME%type;


BEGIN

   IF TRIGER_BY = 'HOD'
   THEN
      OPEN TO_HOD;

      LOOP
         FETCH TO_HOD INTO emp_code,emp_name;

         EXIT WHEN TO_HOD%NOTFOUND;
         counter:=TO_HOD%ROWCOUNT;
      END LOOP;
   ELSIF TRIGER_BY = 'ZONE'
   THEN
      OPEN TO_ZONE;

      LOOP
         FETCH TO_ZONE INTO emp_code,emp_name;

         EXIT WHEN TO_ZONE%NOTFOUND;
         counter:=TO_ZONE%ROWCOUNT;
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
```

here i extract the data that i store in loop in above code

this loop extract the data

```
for i in 1..counter  loop

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (emp_code||' '||emp_name);
         --EXIT WHEN CUR_VAL is null;
      end loop;
    END;
    /
```

**but same row is repeated**

Comment: You can try to use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` in your queries

Comment: You asked almost the same question already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127169/how-to-fetch-cursor-value-with-rowtype. What is your actual problem you try to solve? Currently your code (as written) does not do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

`emp_code` and `emp_name` are scalars.  That is, they only store one value.  Each time you fetch data into them, you are overwriting the prior value.  If you are trying to print the data at the end, `emp_code` and `emp_name` will only have the last values that were fetched and you'll repeat that many times.

Why are you using explicit cursors in the first place (which, incidentally, you've failed to close)?  If, as I'm guessing, you're new to PL/SQL, you're better off using implicit cursors.

```
   IF TRIGER_BY = 'HOD'
   THEN
     for rec in to_hod
     loop
       dbms_output.put_line( rec.employee_code || ' ' || rec.emp_name );
     end loop;
   ELSIF triger_by = 'ZONE'
   THEN
     for rec in to_zone
     loop
       dbms_output.put_line( rec.employee_code || ' ' || rec.emp_name );
     end loop;
   END IF;
```

Now, you could use implicit cursors, declare local collection types rather than local scalar variables, do a `bulk collect` from the cursor into that collection type, and then iterate through the collection in a subsequent step.  But I am guessing that is more than you really want to do.

Comment: actually i want to make a malining procedure you know it has large data in body tag so i dont want to make new body tag for each if else condition thats way i want to use %type or %rowtype variable and extract this in new loop

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  Are you saying that you want to fetch the data into a local collection via a `bulk collect`?  In which case the local variables would need to be collections rather than scalars and you'd realistically want to define your own record or object type and a collection of those records or objects (either separately as first-class objects or as local types).  If you are fetching large amounts of data, though, storing everything in a local collection will likely make your DBA rather upset.  In either case, you won't be using anchored types.